# Mathmatically analizing different voltages in a phase changing circuit

Tags: capacitor, resistors, oscillator, math

I am trying to understand a phase shift oscillator from a mathematical perspective, and to begin I simply took the phase-shifting part of the circuit and am now trying to analyze the voltages as a function of time. Essentially, I'm looking for a way to find the voltages across each component. Normally, something like this would be easy to find using basic equations and grouping, but in this specific application, I can't even find a way to group the components together. Here is the circuit:[image]

My best guess on how to solve this is to find the impedance of each capacitor as a relation to time by working left to right. But in order to find this impedance, I also need to know the current through each capacitor as a relation of time. But in order to know that I would think that I would need to know the V-Out voltage. It seems that in whichever way I try to solve this, I end up going in a loop with all the equations. Also, just for informative purposes, I plan on graphing all the voltages on Desmos.

Is there anything that I am missing? I really am stumped here and any help would be appreciated. Also, I have only taken high school physics at this point and haven't had a chance to get into the calculus bits yet, so if its at all possible to answer the question without calculus, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you learned about phasors yet?

Comment: No I haven't, but based off of a quick Wikipedia search, they don't seem too complicated and chances are I will be able to understand an answer that includes them.

Comment: Personally I would drop the resistor \$R_0\$ at the end of the string and just keep \$R_L\$ since that is the voltage phase/output you care about. If you know how to transform the capacitors to impedances (\$Z_C = 1/j\omega C\$), you can then just apply series / parallel transformations back to your source (which you should add). I'm impressed you're learning this in high-school though, good luck!

Comment: Why are you trying to waste your time with such mathematical exercises? My recommendation: At first, analyze a single R-C or C-R stage (or both) in the frequency domain and understand the magnitude and phase relations. As a second step, realize that 3 stages in series form a 3rd-order system with a maximum phase shift that is three times as large as a 1st order system has (270 deg). From this, it follows that in between there must be a frequency with a phase shift of 180deg (as required for your phase shift oscillator). For exact calculations you can use a suitable program.

Comment: this should give you the answer you seek http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/oscillator/rc_oscillator.html

Comment: @JImDearden, That link explains what I needed. I'm surprised I did not come across that sooner. If you would like to post that as an answer, I will be willing to accept it.